# REnaming activity types

Tags: activities

I want to do a bit of light housekeeping on the activity types in CiviCRM.

I have one activity type called "Internal Client Referral Form" which is used in the webform called "Internal Client Referral Form". (Surprisingly enough).

But also gets used in a couple of other places as a generic referral activity.

If I dive in and edit the activity name down to "Referral", is that going to have knock on effects in other parts of Civi?

I get the feeling that this should be straightforward, which makes me think that I'm overlooking something fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `name` or `label`? The `label` (what is displayed to users, and changeable on the activity type editing form in the UI) is changeable (any non-english site has a different label already). The `name` (civicrm_option_value.name in the database) might be used by extensions or custom code, and is used by civicase. It is not recommended to change the `name` - think of it like a numeric lookup key: If it was "4" instead of a word you wouldn't change it.

Comment: Thanks Demerit.

I meant Label.

I thought that was the case, just wanted to double check before making even a small change to an activity type that is in heavy use.